# Java - How to delete files from a folder in Java?

Tags: java, file, delete-file

I'm trying to delete files using a for-loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

   String pathName = "test" + i + ".csv";
   boolean success = (new File(pathName)).delete();

}
```

But this code deletes only the first file, but not the other ones.

Comment: What are your file names? Are they really `test0.csv`, `test1.csv`, `test2.csv`? Try printing `success` in the for loop, what does it print?

Comment: What are the names of the file, you want to delete?

Comment: File names are really ```test0.csv```, ```test1.csv```, ...

Comment: You can check exists before deleting the file.

Comment: Did you mean all these 3 files - **test0.csv**, **test1.csv** and **test2.csv** - are put in the same file path, but only test0.csv was deleted afterrunning your code?

Comment: That's exactly what happens

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Maybe the path where your files are located is incorrect.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    boolean success = (new File("C:\\Users\\Suppada-Aide\\Desktop\\test"+i+".txt")).delete();
    System.out.println(success);
}
```

Comment: The path is the same of the first file. But it works only for the first file.